# How to show author in blog post in Orchard CMS

Tags: orchardcms

I want to show the Author in Blog Post In OrchardCms.but I don't know how to do this.can anyone help me please?

Comment: Are you want to enter author name for every post as text? or you will have a predefined list of authors to select from?

Comment: @mdameer I want to show the Author name near the blog post summary when somebody publish a post.but I don't know how to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(As always in Orchard, ) You have multiple options for this. The simplest one would be to create an alternate for the Content-BlogPost.cshtml, and put in something like:

```
@ {
    var commonPart = Model.ContentItem.As<ICommonPart>();
    var userName = commonPart.Owner.UserName;
}

<h1>@T("Author"): @userName</h1>
```

Comment: On latest orchard-1.10.1 I cannot find Content-BlogPost.cshtml

Comment: @AtiqRahman you can create it in your theme, that's called an alternate (/override)

Comment: I add this Content-BlogPost.cshtml to Views/Items/ right? It's throwing error.

Comment: here's the error: Views\Items\Content-BlogPost.cshtml(2,43): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ICommonPart' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: You should place it in YourTheme/Views/Content-BlogPost.cshtml. The namespace errors are just in your VS, Orchard's dynamic compiler will find the namespace correctly. If you want to get rid of it in VS, you can add a reference to the project where it's in

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @devcon. I have a slightly different question now. This only shows the user name. What is a good store and retrieve the full name of author/user in orcardcms ?

Comment: That fully depends on how you have attached those fields/properties to your user. If it is just an input field attached to the userpart, you can just do something like `var name = Model.ContentItem.CommonPart.Owner.FullName;`

Answer (score 1):

The best way to achieve this, is by adding new part called `AuthorPart`, and attach it to `BlogPost` type. [This link](http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Writing-a-content-part/) is a tutorial from Orchard site on how to create new part and build the display for it:

Comment: No need for a new part as the author is already on the common part.